# share wso2 EI rest apis source code on the SVN between the developers team

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 EI for designing our APIS.
however, when sharing the source code to the SVN repository, and check out again from another developer machine, the projects created does not exist under the composite application in order to check the dependencies and create a .CAR file.

what is the best way to share the source code of wso2 APIS between team member?.

Comment: do you use the synapse configuration projects in WSO2 Developer Studio?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by synapse configuration projects in WSO2 developer studio?
we are actually using eclipse provided by WSO2 and the SVN kit with no extra configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When sharing the projects to SVN you should follow these recommendations:

- You can ignore the .settings directory and target the directory that’s being source controlled. Add these to ignore list in the respective source control (Git or SVN) system
- Do not ignore the artifacts.xml file and .project file as these contain the data required to display the project
- For ESB projects you can ignore the ‘graphical-synapse-config’ directory as this is auto generated (note that WSO2 DevStudio 3.8.0, onwards graphical files will not being used)

as documented in the following article:
https://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-wso2-developer-studio-development-and-deployment-best-practices/

You can find at the following link some best practices to develop your integration projects:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/WSO2+Enterprise+Integrator+Best+Practices